# SQL Replace query to remove prefix from name contains (MR., MRS., MR / MRS.....)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table of content like this

**tblEmployees**

```
employeeID       employeeName
___________________________________
    1       Jeffrey L. JR Van Hoosear
    2       DAVID GUNGNER MR
    3       CATHLEEN E STADECKER MRS.
    4       MARTIN W SCHIFFMILLER
    5       JAY F MOLDOVANYI VI
```

and Another table like this

**tblPrefix**

```
prefixID       Prefix
_________________________
    1           JR
    2           MR
    3           MR / MRS
    4           JR.
    5           MRS.
    6           I
    7           II
    8           III
    9           IV
   10           V
   11           VI
   12           VII
```

Now i would like to remove prefix (JR, JR., MR, MRS.....) present in EmployeeName.

i have written a function.
For that function i have passed Employee name as parameter like this

```
SELECT * FROM fn_SplitName (@employeeName) (Table-Valued Function)
```

and i tried like this

```
SELECT REPLACE(@employeeName,preFix,'') 
FROM tblPrefix 
WHERE @employeeName LIKE '% ' + preFix + ' %'
```

**expected outPut**

```
employeeID       employeeName
___________________________________
    1       Jeffrey L. Van Hoosear
    2       DAVID GUNGNER
    3       CATHLEEN E STADECKER
    4       MARTIN W SCHIFFMILLER
    5       JAY F MOLDOVANYI
```

Compare with first tblEmpoyee

Comment: can u give u r expected output for the five employee names

Comment: What if somebody has (for example) mr in their name? You properly need some length check to verify that the "part" you're replacing is actually your prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Query:**

```
select employeeName, REPLACE(employeeName, PREFIX,'')  
from employee_table, prefix_table
WHERE INSTR(employeeName, PREFIX) > 0
```

In **SQL-Server**, I think it should be:

```
select employeeName, REPLACE(employeeName, PREFIX,'')  
from employee_table, prefix_table
WHERE CHARINDEX(PREFIX,employeeName) > 0
```

Comment: In tblPrefix table values like (JR,JR.) are there your outPut is Row1: effrey L.  Van Hoosear,Row2: effrey L. JR an Hoosear

Comment: Do you mean to say, the first letter 'J' of 'Jeffrey' is cut too????? Until you have a prefex as 'J', it is not possible

Comment: Exactly i will explain clearly what i have done. "
DECLARE "@namePrefix" VARCHAR(6999)=
 'JR.,JR,SR.,MR. & MRS.,MR.& MRS.,MR.&MRS.' and i have passed this parameter to function fn_Split and it will split the string with comma seperated and will give output as two columns ID and Prefix. now i passed @employeeFullName containing prefixes(JR. or JR or MR. ..etc;) to another function like fn_SplitName(@employeeName) and this function should return employee name which i have passed with out prefix. "

Comment: May be my other answer would help you. Please check. It is similar to your query with additional OR conditions for better validations.

Comment: @Dineshalla: This answer was accepted earlier. Now why unaccept? Any reasons?

Comment: @Dineshalla: Won't a distinct solve duplicates issue?? Does my other answer help?

Comment: ADD top 1 distinct in ur code then it is correct. @Nishanthi Grashia

Answer (score 1):

The following query selects employeeNames that start or end with a prefix. Then, the prefix is stripped off the employeeName using the `SUBSTRING` function.

**EDIT**:
Corrected the CASE statement.

```
SELECT te.employeeName, 
    CASE
        WHEN te.employeeName like '%'+' '+tp.Prefix THEN SUBSTRING(te.employeeName, 1, LEN(te.employeeName)-LEN(tp.Prefix)-1)
        WHEN te.employeeName like tp.Prefix+' '+'%' THEN SUBSTRING(te.employeeName, LEN(tp.Prefix)+2, LEN(te.employeeName)-LEN(tp.Prefix)-1)
    END employeeName_without_Prefix
FROM tblEmployees te
INNER JOIN tblPrefix tp ON te.employeeName like '%'+' '+tp.Prefix OR te.employeeName like tp.Prefix+' '+'%';
```

The above query would not unintentionally replace prefix characters that occur in the middle of the employeeName.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d658f/2)</kbd>

You can embed the SQL statement in a function, as below. However, please note that the function would perform slower, as it is executed for each employeeName one by one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.remove_prefix (@employeeName varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @employeeName_without_Prefix   varchar(100)

SELECT @employeeName_without_Prefix = 
    CASE
        WHEN te.employeeName like '%'+' '+tp.Prefix THEN SUBSTRING(te.employeeName, 1, LEN(te.employeeName)-LEN(tp.Prefix)-1)
        WHEN te.employeeName like tp.Prefix+' '+'%' THEN SUBSTRING(te.employeeName, LEN(tp.Prefix)+2, LEN(te.employeeName)-LEN(tp.Prefix)-1)
    END employeeName_without_Prefix
FROM tblEmployees te
INNER JOIN tblPrefix tp ON te.employeeName like '%'+' '+tp.Prefix OR te.employeeName like tp.Prefix+' '+'%';
     RETURN (@employeeName_without_Prefix);
END;
```

**Reference**:

[Create Function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Comment: Your case statement works fine but i need to implement it in function so that i will send employeename as parameter @employeeName to that function and it will return each employee.

Comment: There is documentation and examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx to create functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can also be changed as:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@employeeName,preFix,'') 
FROM tblPrefix 
WHERE 
(
@employeeName LIKE '% ' + preFix + ' %'
OR @employeeName LIKE '%' + preFix + ' %'
OR @employeeName LIKE '% ' + preFix + '%'
OR @employeeName LIKE '%' + preFix + '%'
);
```

You need to handle scenarios where name may be in following cases:

- `'(space)PREFIX(space)'` --> Name containing prefix in between surrounded by spaces.

  Example: Jeffrey L. JR Van Hoosear
- `'PREFIX(space)'`  --> Name beginning with prefix followed by space followed by name

  Example: JR Jeffrey
- `'(space)PREFIX'` --> Name ending with space and prefix

  Example: Jeffrey JR
- `'PREFIX'`    --> Without space

  Example: JR

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
| Jeffrey L. JR Van Hoosear |
|         GEORGE WASHINGTON |
|           MARTHA D CUSTIS |
|          JOHN VON NEUMANN |
|          ROBERT G MONDAVI |
```

which does not resolve " JR " was produced by:

```
select
        ca3.employeeName
from tblEmployees 
cross apply (
             select
                    charindex(' ',employeeName)
                  , charindex(' ',reverse(employeeName))
                  , len(employeeName)
            ) ca1 (posl, posr, wide)
cross apply (
             select 
                    case when posl > 1 then left(employeeName,posl-1) end
                  , case when posr > 1 then right(employeeName,posr-1) end
            ) ca2 (bitl, bitr)
cross apply (
             select 
                    case
                         when bitl in (select prefix from tblPrefix) then
                                 substring(employeeName,posl+1,wide)
                         when bitr in (select prefix from tblPrefix) then
                                 substring(employeeName,1,wide - posr)
                         else
                              employeeName
                    end
            ) ca3 (employeeName)
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d297b/11)

It would also fail on "MR / MRS"

Comment: " DECLARE "@namePrefix" VARCHAR(6999)= 'JR.,JR,SR.,MR. & MRS.,MR.& MRS.,MR.&MRS.' and i have passed this parameter to function fn_Split and it will split the string with comma seperated and will give output as two columns ID and Prefix. now i passed @employeeFullName containing prefixes(JR. or JR or MR. ..etc;) to another function like fn_SplitName(@employeeName) and this function should return employee name which i have passed with out prefix. "

Answer (score 0):

Use this query in your function. IT will remove Prefix appearing at start, end and in middle

```
SELECT REPLACE(@employeeName,preFix,'') 
FROM tblPrefix 
WHERE @employeeName LIKE '% ' + preFix + ' %'
OR @employeeName LIKE '% ' + preFix
OR @employeeName LIKE preFix + ' %'
```